# Meaning of Gauss curvature of a surface in general 3-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, surfaces, curvature

Let $(\Sigma,g)$ be a surface isometrically embedded in a $3$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,\bar{g})$. I'm particularly interested in the case where the ambient space $(M,\bar{g})$ is *not* the flat Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$. I would like to seek for a clarification of the definition of Gauss curvature:

Is $K$ defined by

1. the determinant of the shape operator $S$? or
2. the sectional curvature $R_{1221}=Rm(e_1,e_2,e_2,e_1)$ (where $Rm$ is the Riemann curvature tensor of $g$ and $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is a local orthonormal frame on $\Sigma$)?

When $(M,\bar{g})$ is the flat $\mathbb{R}^3$, these two notions coincide by the *Theorema Egregium* of Gauss, but in general they certainly do not agree. In fact, by Gauss equation, we have
\begin{align}
2R_{1221}=2\bar{R}_{1221}+H^2-|A|^2
\end{align}
where

- $\bar{R}_{1221}=\bar{Rm}(e_1,e_2,e_2,e_1)$ ($\bar{Rm}$ is the Riemann curvature tensor of $\bar{g}$, and we regard $e_1,e_2$ as tangent vectors in $TM$),
- $H=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ is the mean curvature (sum of principal curvatures), and
- $|A|^2=\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2$ is the norm-square of 2nd fundamental form.

Thus, it follows that 
\begin{align}
\det(S)=\lambda_1\lambda_2=R_{1221}-\bar{R}_{1221}
\end{align}
which certainly does not equal to $R_{1221}$.

I'm asking this because $K$ is defined in the 1st way in many text, but at the same time they seems to also claim the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, which holds only if $K$ is defined in the 2nd way. This is pretty confusing. (Of course, it is also possible that I have made some mistakes somewhere around. I welcome any correction.)

Any comment and answer are greatly welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: What *Is* the shape operator in your general setting?

Comment: @TedShifrin In local expression, it is still given by $h^i_j=g^{ik}h_{kj}$, where $h_{kj}$ is the (components of) 2nd fundamental form.

Comment: The point is that Gaussian curvature is intrinsic, i.e., depends only on the metric, and not on the embedding in the ambient 3-manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. What about the scalar second fundamental form? Actually here I am always working with the scalar one, where $h_{ij}=-\bar{g}(\bar{\nabla}_{e_i}e_j,\nu)$. I thought this is common when codim $=1$. Sorry for not making it explicit.  // 

In order for Gauss curvature to be intrinsic, it seems that the 2nd way would be the correct one, since $R_{1221}$ is completely determined by $g$ itself.

Comment: @TedShifrin Why doesn't Gaussian curvature depend on the embedding? Isn't the induced metric formed from the pullback by the embedding?

Comment: @Boar Reread the first sentence of the OP :)